# how to get exchanges between seller and buyer using one select query

Tags: sql

I have a trade table which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to get the number of exchanges between seller and buyer.

the output of the query should looks like this

[image: output]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases support the `least()` and `greatest()` functions:

```
select least(seller, buyer), greatest(seller, buyer), count(*)
from t
group by least(seller, buyer), greatest(seller, buyer);
```

In databases that do not, there are other approaches.  One uses `case` expressions.  Another `union all`:

```
select seller, buyer, count(*)
from ((select seller, buyer
       from t
       where seller < buyer
      ) union all
      (select buyer, seller
       from t
       where seller > buyer
      )
     ) sb
group by seller, buyer;
```